# Allow internet users to access privately hosted website pages

Tags: apache, networking, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, vpn

I have a corporate private network(VPN) and on one VM a website is hosted which can be accessed internally only. e.g. https://internal.com/welcome.html

Now, I want to allow few pages of the site to be accessible from outside but with their own url.

e.g. they will open http://theirdoamin.com/welcome.html which will be redirected into my private network and internally it will be mapped/proxied to https://internal.com/welcome.html.

This way outside will never know the actual url (i.e https://internal.com/welcome.html.

My question is, can we achieve this using Apache Reverse proxy server sitting in-front of my hosted VM?

Second question, can I also limit the access to welcome.html page only and not others?

My colleague already implemented using Apache Nifi but I still believe it can be simple done using Apache Reverse Proxy setup.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, Apache reverse-proxy is able to do that.
2) You can limit access as you like.

1) I'd set up two [vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/) (for [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)), one with the original name and one with the VPN-accessable name.

```
Listen 80

#If you are running a Apache 2.2 you'll need the following line, for 2.4 you won't
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "srv/www/example1"
    ServerName internal.com

    <Directory "/srv/www/example1">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Other directives here, if needed
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName external.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ https://internal.com/welcome.html [P]
    ProxyPassReverse / https://internal.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need the RewriteRule to target a specific file instead of a whole domain. Otherwise a simple `ProxyPass` would have been enough.

This requires the modules `mod_rewrite`, `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` to be activated.

2) is done by the RewriteRule. It only allows access to that specific target-file (welcome.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response with detailed explanation and example. I will try to implement and hopefully it should be done.